# How to install g++ 4.7.2 & c++11 on CentOS 5.x?

Tags: centos, software-installation, c++, g++

I'm trying to install the latest stable `g++` and `c++11`.  My host did it through `yum install` and thought that it was the latest, but it's not, and they are now saying that this is beyond their level of support.

I've looked all over on how to do this, and I can't make anything work, or I have no idea what the suggested solution is saying.

What's the easiest way to install `g++` 4.7.2 and `c++11` on CentOS **5.9**?

Comment: I don't see anything in that that (in my _very_ inexperienced eyes) requires some new C++ feature. To install extra software (from source, no less) isn't to be taken lightly (if you are using CentOS, it is presumably a enterprisey application). Not for somebody with _hours_ of Linux experience, in any case. Reconsider your options carefully.

Comment: what does require lambda so insistently? Perhaps your best bet is to install latest Fedora, where gcc-4.7.2 is the default compiler, _maintained by the distribution_?

Comment: I'm no C++ expert, but "sort by N-th int in a vector of int" requires a comparison between vectors, and that is _not_ an exotic requirement only to be fullfilled with latest C++. Sure, it might be easier, but if something that simple couldn't be done from the very first versions of STL, I'd be completely flabbergasted. Get a C++ expert on board?

Comment: Have you considered the BOOST libraries? A large percentage of C++11 came from there...

Comment: c++11 isn't compiler , it's a standard. see my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/542091/191578) to "Install gcc 4.7 on CentOS [6.x]", the easiest way to get `g++` 4.7, and the required tools and libraries, for CentOS 5.x is via the `devtools` package:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools/devtools.repo 
yum --enablerepo=testing-devtools-6 install devtoolset-1.0
```

Since you're running `g++` manually (as opposed to through `make`), you'll need to update your `$PATH` variable so your shell will use the new `gcc`, `g++`, etc. binaries:

```
export PATH=/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.0/root/usr/bin/:$PATH
```

At this point, your `g++` should be version 4.7.0

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.7.0 20120507 (Red Hat 4.7.0-5)
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

---

Be aware that installing `gcc` and associated tools and libraries in this manner relies on the repository maintainer to keep their packages up to date.

If you're interested in keeping your `gcc` up to date, you may want to consider [building `gcc` from source](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/).

Also, compiling programs with a different version of `g++` and `libstdc++` than are installed on your system can cause all kinds of [Fun](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Fun), coping with which is beyond the scope of this answer. It may be worth moving to a Linux distribution that has support for what you're doing.

Comment: I've updated the instructions -- the package you want `yum` to install is `devtoolset-1.0`, as that contains other required development tools; and you'll want to update your `$PATH` variable since you're launching `g++` from the command line.

Comment: When I create a new console, gcc is still on the old version. How do I make the new version the default?

Comment: To set this permanently, you have to add the `export PATH..` line in your ~/.profile or ~./profile_bash or equivalent: http://superuser.com/questions/809250/centos-set-environment-variable-permanently

Comment: Still shows "g++ (GCC) 4.1.2" after this :-(

Answer (score 1):

Package managers are great, but (understandably) won't generally include the latest version of software. CentOS being a distribution particularly focusing on servers, favors stability (and extensive testing) over having the latest and shiniest. Here are your solutions:

**Change distro**

Other distributions like Arch Linux, Sabayon Linux or Debian "Sid" include newest versions a lot faster. You may consider changing distros.

**Build it yourself**

If you're stuck with CentOS, your best bet is to [build gcc from source](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/). It means getting the source code, making sure the [dependencies are already present on your system](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html) (if not, I'm sure you can get them from the CentOS package manager), compiling the source into a binary executable, and [installing the executable on your system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63531/how-to-truely-install-a-tar-gz-file-on-linux-how-to-manage-manually-installed/63542#63542).

It's not the easiest way to do it for sure, but you'll learn a lot about Unix in the process. Make sure to read the document a few times to make sure you get everything, and ask questions if something specific is unclear.

**Be patient**

At some point, this version (or newer) of gcc/g++ is going to enter the package manager. If you wait (up to several months, I'm not very familiar with the CentOS release cycle), you'll ultimately get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I'm too new to comment on Reed's answer. It worked well for me. Only thing I wanted to note (maybe this is something for Reed?) is that I had to install with a slightly different command line:

```
yum --enablerepo=testing-devtools-5 install devtoolset-1.0
```

(Reed's answer had `--enablerepo=testing-devtools-6`, which didn't work.)